# active model serializer flat structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, active-model-serializers, rails-api, flat

I'm bulding my api server for my React/Redux app, where i need some flat response from server to manage and reduce my state.

For example, when i have this response:

```
[{
  id: 1,
  title: 'Some Article',
  author: {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Dan'
  }
}, {
  id: 2,
  title: 'Other Article',
  author: {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Dan'
  }
}]
```

How can i make it looks like:

```
{
  result: [1, 2],
  entities: {
    articles: {
      1: {
        id: 1,
        title: 'Some Article',
        author: 1
      },
      2: {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Other Article',
        author: 1
      }
    },
    users: {
      1: {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Dan'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Best feature is what each key is articles/users id, so i can easily get it from the response and merge it in my front-end app.

Comment: Why not use [JSONAPI](http://jsonapi.org/)? There already is an adapter for AMS.

Comment: @max, because it doesn't get me flat response; response will be more nested then now. in my react/redux app i should merge some data from response with some state i already have, without normalizing it's hard to do.

Comment: I assume you've seen the Normalizr library: https://github.com/gaearon/normalizr which is designed to exactly solve this problem - it even appears that this is where you got the example of desired output

Comment: @Joshua, yes, i've seen it. but i wanna my rails-app to send me response with the format like that.

anybody knows how to do this with AMS or any other kind of serializers?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with AMS, but you will have to write a custom adapter, as none of the stock ones provide this exact format.

JSON API (and the corresponding AMS `JsonApi` adapter) solve this issue, but the format is slightly different from the one you want.